# mimic iii: could a pretrained word2vec be made available?

Tags: mimic-iii, nlp, legal

Why reinvent the wheel? or would this be some sort of a breach since it would then be available to those who have not taken the ethics course?

Comment: Sorry, I fail to see why *those who have not taken the ethics course* is relevant here? It is either legal or illegal.

Comment: Prerequisite? Ok illegal

Answer (score 1):

I trained word embeddings based on mimic, e.g. for https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.09704 and https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.08705,  but publicly releasing them would go against the agreement one signs when getting access to mimic. However, they could be made available on https://physionet.org/

Comment: Thanks so very much for the great idea and all the research  on mimic. I assume non mit folks cannot upload anything on physionet but would you be able and kind enough to do so? I am probably already citing a lot of your work and cannot offer much in return, sorry.

Comment: also did you only train it on discharge summaries or was it trained on the entire free text available?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a word2vec pre-trained with MIMIC-III and PubMed on Github:
https://github.com/ncbi-nlp/BioSentVec